# Unit Testing MVC Web Application in Visual Studio and Problem with QTAgent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have been attempting to run a Unit Test in visual studio for an MVC Application and continuously getting the following error:

> The URL specified ('http://localhost:21496/') does not correspond to a
>   valid directory. Tests configured to run in ASP.NET in IIS require a
>   valid directory to exist for the URL. The URL may be invalid or may
>   not point to a valid Web application.

The only advice around is to make sure you have a localhost address in the UrlToTest attribute like so:

> ```
>     [TestMethod()]
>     [HostType("ASP.NET")]
>     [UrlToTest("http://localhost:21496/")]
> ```

This however still doesn't run against IIS Express or IIS 7 on Windows 7 and when I delved into the event logs, found the following problem.

```
(QTAgent32.exe, PID 6976, Thread 15) WebSites.GetWebServer: failed to create AspNetHelper: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.AspNetHelperException: The website metabase contains unexpected information or you do not have permission to access the metabase.  You must be a member of the Administrators group on the local computer to access the IIS metabase. Therefore, you cannot create or open a local IIS Web site.  If you have Read, Write, and Modify Permissions for the folder where the files are located, you can create a file system web site that points to the folder in order to proceed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unknown error (0x80005000)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_IsContainer()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.ChildEnumerator..ctor(DirectoryEntry container)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.IISHelper.GetWebServerOrdinal(Uri site)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.IISHelper.GetWebServerOrdinal(Uri site)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.IISHelper.get_WebServerOrdinal()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.IISHelper.get_RootPath()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.IISHelper.get_PhysicalPath()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.AspNetHelperMan..ctor(Uri uri, BasicAuthCredential credential, Int32 frameworkMajorVersion)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.HostAdapters.WebSites.GetWebServer(String webServerName, WebServerType webServerType, String urlToTest, String pathToWeb, String webAppRoot, BasicAuthCredential credential, Context context, WebSiteConfigurationType webSiteConfigType, Origin origin)
```

The next step I took was to make sure the QTAgent32 always runs with administrative privileges, along with visual studio.

I am now at a loss and cannot think of anything else to try, so do hope someone can at least point me in some direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The tests were created in a default ASP.NET environment. In order to test the controllers but without the need to run the web application, you must delete the following attributes before  the  test methods.

```cs
[HostType("ASP.NET")]
[UrlToTest("http://localhost:21496/")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem today (also at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065937/asp-net-unit-testing-windows7-iis7/10467898#10467898)). I had the same errors in my event log:

```
(QTAgent32.exe, PID 12348, Thread 61) WebSites.GetWebServer: failed to create AspNetHelper: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.Common.AspNetHelperException: The website metabase contains unexpected information or you do not have permission to access the metabase.  You must be a member of the Administrators group on the local computer to access the IIS metabase. Therefore, you cannot create or open a local IIS Web site.  If you have Read, Write, and Modify Permissions for the folder where the files are located, you can create a file system web site that points to the folder in order to proceed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unknown error (0x80005000)
```

That lead me to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2010/07/23/tip-fixing-vsperfaspnetcmd-metabase-errors.aspx) which seems to have resolved the issue.

I just needed to go to "Turn Windows features on or off" and add IIS 6 Management Compatibility and all four subcomponents. I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium which doesn't have the Windows Authentication option, but that didn't seem to be an issue. Give it a shot and see if that resolves the issue for you.