# The URL Specified () does not correspond to a valid directory.

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

When trying to run a unit test I get this error:

> Test Name:    GetMethodTest Test
>   FullName: Quanser.Codex.App.Web.Repository.UnitTests.DocumentsControllerTests.GetMethodTest
>   Test Source:  c:\Dev\Engineering\Mobile
>   Apps\Software\Codex\trunk\Web\Repository\UnitTests.Repository\DocumentsControllerTests.cs
>   : line 34 Test Outcome:   Failed Test Duration:   0:00:00
>
> Result Message:   The URL specified ('http://localhost:53364/') does not
>   correspond to a valid directory. Tests configured to run in ASP.NET in
>   IIS require a valid directory to exist for the URL. The URL may be
>   invalid or may not point to a valid Web application.

This is my test case:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [HostType("ASP.NET")]
    [UrlToTest("http://localhost:53364/")]
    public void GetMethodTest() 
    {
      // ...
    }
```

I know there is something wrong with this line:

```
 [UrlToTest("http://localhost:53364/")]
```

What should I put as the Url in this attribute?

Note: I need to use these attributes for testing the REST API

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it's a permission issue as described in [this post][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065937/asp-net-unit-testing-windows7-iis7

Answer (score 1):

Those attributes are for testing ASP.NET Web Forms projects.  If you only need to test your WebAPI Controllers then you should be able to just delete them, e.g.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void GetMethodTest() 
{
  // ...
}
```